# How to render a graph in a View only after the filters on a Partial View have been chosen in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, graph, partial-views

I have an **ASP.NET MVC3** application in **C#** and **Razor**.

I want to create a page with filters (such as year, month) and once the user selects the filters and click the submit button, a graph is displayed. I use the following code (not working):
**View** Stats.cshtml

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

@{ Html.RenderPartial("StatsFilter", Model.FilterViewModel);  }

<img src="@Url.Action("DrawChart")" alt="Drawing chart with HTML Helper" />
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Stats", StatsViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FiltersViewModel filters)
        {
            //Retrieve Data
            return View("Stats", StatsViewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult DrawChart(GraphViewModel graph)
        {
            var chart = new Chart(width: 500, height: 600)
                .AddTitle("Chart Title")
                .AddSeries(
                            chartType: "Line",
                            name: "Stats",
                            xValue: chartData.XValues.Keys.ToList(),
                            yValues: chartData.XValues.Values.ToList())
                .GetBytes("png");
            return File(chart, "image/bytes");
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class StatsViewModel
{
    public FilterViewModel Filters { get; set; }
    public GraphViewModel Graph { get; set; }
}
```

With such solution, I do not know how to pass the ViewModel to the graph. Moreover, if I make some small adjustments (like removing the `GraphViewModel` also from the `DrawChart` action method) the Graph is displayed anyway, even without data.

I would like to give the user the possibility to choose the filters and then display the Graph. I hope I am in the right path and my code is not to be thrown away completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GraphViewModel graph` is not used anywhere in your controller. So you don't need this parameter.

But in case you need to pass some vales to your controller then you can do it with query string in the url.